# go mars rover kata go

Tags: go

A [kata](https://kata-log.rocks/index.html) is an exercise. In martial art is form. In software development is a way to practicing. For example in [TDD](https://kata-log.rocks/tdd).

[Mars rover kata](https://kata-log.rocks/mars-rover-kata) aims to solve some problem in the context of the mars rover. Here you can find a list of kata. kata-log.rocks/mars-rover-kata Kata are exercises you can use to practicing in tdd, in pair or alone.

Mars rover kata rules are:

- You are given the initial starting point (x,y) of a rover and the direction (N,S,E,W) it is facing.
- The rover receives a character array of commands.
- Implement commands that move the rover forward/backward (f,b).
- Implement commands that turn the rover left/right (l,r).
- Implement wrapping at edges. But be careful, planets are spheres.  - Connect the x edge to the other x edge, so (1,1) for x-1 to (5,1), but connect vertical edges towards themselves in inverted coordinates, so (1,1) for y-1 connects to (5,1).
- Implement obstacle detection before each move to a new square. If a given sequence of commands encounters an obstacle, the rover moves up to the last possible point, aborts the sequence and reports the obstacle.

I am playing with mars rover kata and this is the complete result:

```golang
package main

import (
     "fmt"
)

type Point struct {
    x int
    y int
}

type Sphere struct {
    firstCorner Point
    lastCorner Point
    obstacles []Point
}

type Rover struct {
    position Point
    direction string
    world Sphere
}

func (r *Rover) moves (moves []string) {
    for _, m := range moves {
        r.move(m)
    }
}

func (r *Rover) move (command string) {
    if command == "l" {
        if r.direction == "e" { r.direction = "n"; return }
        if r.direction == "s" { r.direction = "e"; return }
        if r.direction == "w" { r.direction = "s"; return }
        if r.direction == "n" { r.direction = "w"; return }
    }
    if command == "r" {
        if r.direction == "n" { r.direction = "e"; return }
        if r.direction == "e" { r.direction = "s"; return }
        if r.direction == "s" { r.direction = "w"; return }
        if r.direction == "w" { r.direction = "n"; return }
    }
    if command == "f" {
        if r.direction == "n" { r.update(r.position.x,r.position.y+1) }
        if r.direction == "s" { r.update(r.position.x,r.position.y-1) }
        if r.direction == "w" { r.update(r.position.x-1,r.position.y) }
        if r.direction == "e" { r.update(r.position.x+1,r.position.y) }
    }
    if command == "b" {
        if r.direction == "n" { r.update(r.position.x,r.position.y-1) }
        if r.direction == "s" { r.update(r.position.x,r.position.y+1) }
        if r.direction == "w" { r.update(r.position.x+1,r.position.y) }
        if r.direction == "e" { r.update(r.position.x-1,r.position.y) }
    }
}

func (r *Rover) update (x int, y int) {
    if y > r.world.lastCorner.y {
        x,y = r.world.lastCorner.y,x
    }

    if y < r.world.firstCorner.y {
        x,y = r.world.lastCorner.y,r.world.lastCorner.x
    }

    if x < r.world.firstCorner.x {
        x,y = r.world.lastCorner.x, r.world.firstCorner.y
    }

    if x > r.world.lastCorner.x {
        x,y = r.world.firstCorner.x, r.world.firstCorner.y
    }

    isFree := true
    destination := Point{x,y}
    for _, obstacle := range r.world.obstacles {
        if obstacle.x == destination.x && obstacle.y == destination.y {
            isFree = false
        }
    }
    if isFree == true {
        r.position = destination
    }
}

func main() {
     fmt.Println("Mars Rover Kata!")
}
```

I guess there is a way to simplify this code:

```golang
func (r *Rover) move (command string) {
    if command == "l" {
        if r.direction == "e" { r.direction = "n"; return }
        if r.direction == "s" { r.direction = "e"; return }
        if r.direction == "w" { r.direction = "s"; return }
        if r.direction == "n" { r.direction = "w"; return }
    }
    if command == "r" {
        if r.direction == "n" { r.direction = "e"; return }
        if r.direction == "e" { r.direction = "s"; return }
        if r.direction == "s" { r.direction = "w"; return }
        if r.direction == "w" { r.direction = "n"; return }
    }
    if command == "f" {
        if r.direction == "n" { r.update(r.position.x,r.position.y+1) }
        if r.direction == "s" { r.update(r.position.x,r.position.y-1) }
        if r.direction == "w" { r.update(r.position.x-1,r.position.y) }
        if r.direction == "e" { r.update(r.position.x+1,r.position.y) }
    }
    if command == "b" {
        if r.direction == "n" { r.update(r.position.x,r.position.y-1) }
        if r.direction == "s" { r.update(r.position.x,r.position.y+1) }
        if r.direction == "w" { r.update(r.position.x+1,r.position.y) }
        if r.direction == "e" { r.update(r.position.x-1,r.position.y) }
    }
}
```

But I am also afraid to move into unnecessary simplification. I mean: code could be better for computers but worst for humans. And since I am on the side of humans I think this code is good enough. But I also know that go have some idiomatic stuff that can make this code better. Any suggestion?

Comment: When `x` wraps around on a sphere, `y` should stay put. The topology defined by the code looks more like a projective plane to me. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Represent a direction as a `dx, dy` tuple (rather than special-casing `n,s,w,e`. This way, a left turn is `dx, dy = -dy, dx` and a right turn is `dx, dy = dy, -dx`.

Likewise, a forward move is `x += dx, y += dy` and a backward one is `x -= dx, y -= dy`.

Once the move is performed, ypu may check if you fell of the map, and adjust according to a topology.

---

Your `update` doesn't seem to describe the sphere. For example, passing the North Pole on the way to North shall make the rover face South. I don't see the change of direction whatsoever.

Comment: Ok thank you. I know that works because tests works. Maybe also tests should be placed here? But, .. your snippets are very go idiomatic. I really thank you!